# How to download the birt report directly instead of view in the viewer?

Tags: birt

my report is up and running in my local tomcat server with this url

```
http://localhost:8080/WebViewerExample/frameset?__report=course_report.rptdesign
```

so in my report there is one parameter called "course" so in the browser asking for the parameter and displaying the report as per my reports design it's working fine.
But my requirement is instead of view the report in the birt viewer it should be download.
so i am trying to change the url like this
    http://localhost:8080/WebViewerExample/download?__report=course_report.rptdesign&course="MCA"

means in the place of "frameset" i am writting "download" and passing the parameter "&course="MCA".

it's giving an error

- org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: /home/arjunkumarm/tomcat7/webapps/WebViewerExample/documents/BIRTDOC1D8E2827AF9E44F93971829D80BB680C/20150702_181043_534/course_report.rptdocument doesn't exist or is not a folder.

any one can help me what is the error. and what is the solution for that.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Try /executereport.do?__executableName=/MyReport.rptdesign&invokesubmit=true&__format=pdf. You could also do it with JavaScript on a web page or their REST API.

For additional discussion check out http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/23052-using-actuateviewerdownloadreport/

Comment: Hi ! thanks for reply but i am not getting what you want to say ?

Comment: url given by you and and my url pattern is tottly different that's why i am unable to understand

Comment: as your reply i tried but its showing the result in the PDF format .and don't want to show the output to the user instead of that it should be download directly

Comment: Well, that is probably your browser setting to auto-open the PDF.